# Как отправить html таблицу в json?

Tags: html, json

Подскажите, кто знает как можно реализовать данную задачу?

Есть таблица `html`, например такая:

```html
 <table id="students" border="1">
    <tr>
  <td>Value1</td>
  <td>Value2</td>
  <td>Value3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

Ожидаемый json примерно такой:

```
    [
    {"Value1":"1", "Value2":"2",
    "Value3":"3"
     },
     {"Value1":"4", "Value2":"5",
    "Value3":"6"
    }]
```

Как можно передать такую таблицу в json?  Как можно такое реализовать? В каком направлении двигаться не понятно.

Comment: Ваш ожидаемый json нелогичен. Зачем вам каждый раз указывать имя столбца? Вот так было бы адекватнее: `{"Value1": [1, 4], "Value2": [2, 5], "Value3": [3, 6]}`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927126/how-to-convert-the-following-table-to-json-with-javascript

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/4E2L6/9/

Answer (score 1):

Код можно посмотреть на [**СodePen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XqvMwL?editors=1010)

Код работает с любым количеством столбцов и строк

```
$(() => {
const data = [];// Ответ
const nameTd = [];
const Table = $('#students');
const numberTr = Table.find('tr').length; //Количество ячеек по вертикали
const numberTd = Table.find('tr:first > td').length; //Количество ячеек по горизонтали

for (let i = 1; i <= numberTd; i++) {
    nameTd.push(Table.find(`tr:first-child > td:nth-child(${i})`).text());
}

for (let i = 2; i <= numberTr; i++) {
    const objectTd = {};

    for (let k = 0; k < nameTd.length; k++) {
        objectTd[nameTd[k]] = Table.find(`tr:nth-child(${i})>td:nth-child(${k + 1})`).text();
    }

    data.push(objectTd);
}
console.log(data);
});
```